# How to open a new window, which will be a child of the current one and located inside it

Tags: javascript, electron

How to open a new window, which will be a child of the current one and located inside it?
For example: like Google Chrome tabs

Comment: what do you mean "located inside it". windows aren't tabs

Comment: @pushkin but how to implement tabs in one window so that the contents of each tab (for example, styles) do not conflict with the styles of the application or other tabs? That is, so that it works in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right you want to load multiple files in one window without merging their styles. In this case you should take a look at the webview tag. It's like an fully controllable iframe.

See: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What needs to be specified in the src attribute in the webview tag when I use the Vue.js environment?